# Gogland: debugging is grayed out

Tags: debugging, go, goland

I can't seem to get the debugger to run. The debugging run icon is grayed out and the menu options are missing.

[image: Toolbar]

This is only the case for `main`, I can debug unit tests just fine.

Similar questions mention the project structure, but I can't see anything wrong:

```
$GOPATH/src/foo.bar.com/some/more/dirs/
      project/    <-- this directory is opened in Gogland
         app1/
            main.go
         app2/
            main.go
         mylib/
            abc.go
            abc_test.go
```

I can right click on `abc_test.go` and run it with or without debugging, but if I right click on one of the `main.go` files, I can only run it.

Run configuration:

[image: run configuration]

Gogland build 162.12024.32

Comment: Do you have an existing run configuration active when you are trying this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "active". One is selected.

Comment: Yes, that's it. What type of configuration is that? Go Single File? Go Application? Another? A screenshot or anything more detailed out help a lot to reproduce / help with this. Thank you.

Comment: I've added the screenshots. I was using "Go Single File". It seems to be working with "Go Application". If you add an answer, I'll accept. Thanks for poining me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go Single File does not currently support debugging. If such a Run Configuration is active then a new one must be created. The type for the new one must be Go Application.

To create a Go Application Run Configuration you can also choose: Build and run ... from the menu when presented with the option.

Also changing the current active Run Configuration from a Go Single File to a Go Application one will fix the problem.